# QEventLoop: get time when an event was scheduled

Tags: qt, qt5, scheduling, event-loop, qeventloop

Is it possible to get the time when an event has been scheduled to a QEventLoop (e.g. the `QCoreApplication` event loop)?

I have a situation where the main event loop is paused. When it's reactivated the events are fired and I am interested in the time when the events where added to the queue. The events are not custom events but system (and other) events.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on what are the system events you are interested in, for you have already the `timestamp` in some cases.

As an example, `QInputEvent` ([base class for events that describe user input](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputevent.html), like `QMouseEvent`, `QKeyEvent`, and so on) has the [member method timestamp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputevent.html#timestamp) that:

> Returns the window system's timestamp for this event.

In other terms, a timestamp close to the time when it has been pushed into the event loop.

Comment: I am interested in ``QMetaCallEvent`` for instance (http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject_p.h.html#361) which do not have a timestamp. I was already suspecting that there is no generic timestamp when adding it to the central queue due to (in most cases) unnecessary overhead.

Comment: A second event I am interested in is the ``QTimerEvent`` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimerevent.html).

Comment: To be honest, it seems an XY-problem. What do you want to do exactly? Why you are trying to catch the time when an even has been triggered?

Comment: Any idea on how to get a valid timestamp before the timestamp() method was introduced? Unfortunately, I have to use Qt 4.8. for now.

Comment: @FrozenTarzan Unfortunately no, I forgot almost everything related to Qt4 since I started using Qt5. :-)

Comment: @skypjack Sure, may I ask if you have any idea on how to do that on an embedded Linux platform? The time I see input events in my event filter is actually to late already since the event got queued (long) before that. I guess that this should not be a comment but I'm not aware of how to open a "chat" and if that is more appropriate^^

Comment: @FrozenTarzan I'd rather create a dedicated question where you can link this Q/A for further details. There a lot of smart people on SO that can help you.

Comment: @skypjack Thanks! I posted a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816955/get-the-timestamp-when-a-qinputevent-was-put-onto-the-queue-of-the-qeventloop-in

Comment: @skypjack And since you have pointed to an "XY-problem" in one of your older comments I have posted another question regarding the main goal of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817148/how-to-block-ignore-discard-user-input-events-that-are-older-than-a-certain-time